# Evaluating $\mathrm{tr}\left( (\mathbf{D} + \mathbf{A})^{-1}\mathbf{A} \right )$ for symmetric $\mathbf{A}$ and diagonal $\mathbf{D}$

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, inverse, numerical-linear-algebra

For two real and (entrywise) positive $n\times n$ matrices $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{D}$, where $\mathbf{A}$ is symmetric and $\mathbf{D}$ is diagonal, I'd like to evaluate:
$$
f= \mathrm{tr}\left( (\mathbf{D} + \mathbf{A})^{-1}\mathbf{A} \right).\tag{1}
$$

Is there some clever way to approach this which can avoid directly evaluating the matrix inverse $(\mathbf{D} + \mathbf{A})^{-1}$? In my case $n$ is large $(\approx10^5)$ and $\mathbf{A}$ is fairly sparse, so calculating the inverse of $\mathbf{A}+\mathbf{D}$ is difficult.

By the way, we may rewrite $f$ as follows:
\begin{align}
f&= \mathrm{tr}\left( (\mathbf{D} + \mathbf{A})^{-1}(\mathbf{D}+\mathbf{A}-\mathbf{D}) \right)\\
&= n-\mathrm{tr}\left( (\mathbf{D} + \mathbf{A})^{-1}\mathbf{D} \right)\\
&= n-\mathrm{tr}\left( \mathbf{D}^{1/2}(\mathbf{D} + \mathbf{A})^{-1}\mathbf{D}^{1/2} \right)\\
&= n-\mathrm{tr}\left( (I+\mathbf{D}^{-1/2}\mathbf{A}\mathbf{D}^{-1/2})^{-1} \right).\tag{2}
\end{align}
So, we can also obtain the trace by solving the symmetric eigenvalue problem for $I+\mathbf{D}^{-1/2}\mathbf{A}\mathbf{D}^{-1/2}$. But when $\mathbf{A}$ is symmetric, large and sparse, is the eigenvalue problem more tractable than the matrix inversion problem?

Comment: Can you perform any sparse direct factorization of $(D+A)$? If yes, can you afford to solve $n$ linear systems using this factorization? If yes, then the diagonal entries of your matrix can be computed in parallel.

Comment: @user1551 I see how you got to the RHS there, but I can't make the leap to finding the small eigenvalues - what am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: @user1551 I may have missed an assumption, but I  see no guarantee that the spectrum of $M$ is not all over the real line. I don't see how finding the smaller eigenvalues of $M$ helps. Would you add a few words about this?

Comment: @user1551 thanks for the help guys - I did leave out the information that both $\mathbf{A, D}$ have positive entries only - I'll edit the question now.

Comment: @CarlChristian $tr(M^{-1})=\sum_i\lambda_i$. If $M$ happens to be positive definite and ill conditioned, we may ignore the large $\lambda_i$s in the sum. Of course, when $M$ is not positive definite or it is well conditioned, one may need to find all the eigenvalues.

Comment: @user1551 I've added your suggestion as an edit to the question (I hope correctly?) thanks.

Comment: I've made a few edits. Please feel free to roll back.

Comment: @user1551. I combined our comments in to a tentative solution.

Answer (score 1):

At this point it is possible to combine the comments and present at least a first solution which requires mainly sparse matrix vector solves.

In principle, we can compute the trace of $A^{-1}$ using the formula
$$ \text{tr}(A^{-1}) = \sum_{j=1}^n e_j^T A^{-1} e_j,$$
where $e_j$ is the $j$th column vector of the $n$ by $n$ identity matrix.
We should solve the linear systems
$$ Ax_j = e_j$$
and then compute
$$ \text{tr}(A) = \sum_{j=1}^n e_j^T x_j$$
This approach is attractive if it is possible to compute one of the (sparse) factorization of $A$, say, $A = LU$. Then
$$ \text{tr}(A) = \sum_{j=1}^n e_j^T A^{-1} e_j = \sum_{j=1}^n e_j^T U^{-1} L^{-1} e_j.$$
We observe that it suffices to solve the lower triangular linear systems
$$ \quad U^T y_j = e_j \quad Lz_j = e_j $$
and compute
$$ \text{tr}(A) = \sum_{j=1}^n y_j^T z_j.$$

Now, user1551's rewrite suggests that we should compute the trace of the matrix $$G = D^{\frac{1}{2}} (D + A)^{-1} D^{\frac{1}{2}}.$$ It is theoretically possible to factor the symmetric matrix $(D + A)$ as 
$$ D + A = LHL^T$$
where $L$ is lower triangular and $H$ is diagonal, but it need not be practical, due to fill-in during the factorization. In general, this is called an $LDL^T$ factorization, a square root free generalization of Cholesky's algorithm which applies to general symmetric matrices. It follows that
$$ \text{tr}(G) = \sum_{j=1}^n e_j^T D^{\frac{1}{2}}  L^{-T} H^{-1} L^{-1}D^{\frac{1}{2}} e_j.$$
As before, the task reduces to solving lower triangular linear systems, specifically
$$ L w_j = D^{\frac{1}{2}} e_j,$$
applying a diagonal scaling $H^{-1}$, and doing inner products.

If fill-in is a major issue, then iterative methods must be used to solve the necessary linear systems.

From a practical perspective, the approach is attractive, because it offers a way of decoupling the calculation into a sequences of independent problems which can be solved in parallel with no need for communication between the processors.